# JQuery 'dot' exception in form

Tags: jquery, input, text

```
$("#rate_of_pay_after_probation").keypress(function (event) {
    //check_numbers(event);
    if (event.which == 8 || event.which == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    if ((event.which < 44 || event.which > 59 || (event.which > 44 && event.which < 48))) {
        return false;
    }
    if (event.which == 44 && $(this).val().indexOf(',') != -1) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

I can use comma but when it comes to dot i didn't manage to do it.

Comment: Your question is not clear, can you explain "when it comes to dot i didn't manage to do it"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want only float numbers you can test it in this way

```
var regEx= /^((\d+(\.\d *)?)|((\d*\.)?\d+))$/;

if(regEx.test($(this).val().replace(',','.').replace(' ',''))) {
    return false;
}
```

in your example you could put in in a function

```
function testFloat(value){
     var regEx= /^((\d+(\.\d *)?)|((\d*\.)?\d+))$/;

    if(regEx.test(value)) {
        return true; //input is float
    }
    return false;//input is not float
}
```

and then in your function

```
$("#rate_of_pay_after_probation").keypress(function (event) {
    //check_numbers(event);
    if (event.which == 8 || event.which == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    if ((event.which < 44 || event.which > 59 || (event.which > 44 && event.which < 48))) {
        return false;
    }
    if (event.which == 44 && testFloat($(this).val().replace(',','.').replace(' ',''))) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

after some explaination I suggest you to use this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mhj98/) (added event.wich for dots `event.which == 46`)

```
$("#rate_of_pay_after_probation").keypress(function (event) {
    //check_numbers(event);
    if (event.which == 8 || event.which == 0 || event.which == 46) {
        return true;
    }
    if ((event.which < 44 || event.which > 59 || (event.which > 44 && event.which < 48))) {
        return false;
    }
    if (event.which == 44 && $(this).val().indexOf(',') != -1) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: I need to be able to use comma and dot at the same time, for example: 1,200.35. thank you

Comment: and so use `replace(',','')`. in this way you remove commas that are irrilevant for evaluate the number

Comment: @Comisarul try to explain me which is the problem, I can help you to solve it

Comment: Ok, i think there is a problem with understanding. I am suposed to register in the DB the numer exactly like this: 1,320.29 (law issues)

Comment: and as i found the code writen, it is letting me just to use one comma. The user can't add dot in the form. HTML input type is text :)

Comment: i think there are some problems with eevent.which conditions

Comment: so your requests are: 1) one and only one comma 2) one and only one dot?

Comment: show me an invalid input please

Comment: invalid inputs are: 1)letters 2) other signs. There is no problem with numer of commas and dots ( there cand be 1 or more)

Comment: yes, the single problem is that they can't use Dots ;)

Comment: I've done this fiddle for you http://jsfiddle.net/Mhj98/ now works

Comment: can you send it here? because that website doesn't work :) thank you very much for you effort

Comment: I've updated the answer.. look that after "update"

Comment: it's working exactly as i wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

change event type > keyDown

check here >> http://jsfiddle.net/ChoHongRae/F3KHL/

```
 $("#rate_of_pay_after_probation").**keydown**(function (event) {
    //check_numbers(event);
    if (event.which == 8 || event.which == 0) {
        //return true;
    }
    if ((event.which < 44 || event.which > 59 || (event.which > 44 && event.which < 48))) {
       // return false;
    }
    if (event.which == 44 && $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) {
        alert("dot");
        //return false;
    }

     alert(($(this).val().indexOf('.')));

    if ($(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) {
        alert("dot");
        return false;
    }
});
```